# Как опустить прокрутку в самую нижнюю точку блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В этот прокручивающийся блок подгружается динамическое содержимое.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала находим сам элемент(например, блок с классом some-element)

```
var someElement = document.querySelector('.some-element');
```

потом меняем положение скролла

```
someElement.scrollTop = someElement.scrollHeight;
```

и, скорее всего, раз будет подгружаться еще контент и, соответственно, от этого будет меняться высота блока, то нужно будет после подгрузки новых элементов опять прокручивать вниз

```
someElement.scrollTop = someElement.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сделал так:
    $(function() {
            scrollDown();
    });

    function scrollDown() {
            
            
            var someElement = document.querySelector('#panel-body-id');
            
            someElement.scrollTop = someElement.scrollHeight;
            
        }


И на методе, где подгружаю контент - в конце вызываю метод scrollDown()